# Big Query Gap Fill in group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get all of table A to repeat for every customer in table B  so far my process is as follows:

Table A:

```
  PStage  StageOrder
  pros   1
  dis    2
  qual   3
  val    4
  prop   5
  neg    6
  stal   7
  won    8
```

Table B:

```
 ID  stage   
 A   Dis      
 A   Won
```

From there I more or less get what I want by

Select
A.* , B.*
left join on a.pstage = b.Stage

so I get

```
PStage  StageOrder  ID    stage
  pros      1        null  null
  dis       2         A    dis
  qual      3        null  null
  val       4        null  null
  prop      5        null  null
  neg       6        null  null
  stal      7        null  null
  won       8         A    won
```

But when Table B is

```
 ID  stage   
 A   dis      
 A   won  
 B   dis 
 B   neg
```

I get

```
PStage  StageOrder  ID    stage
  pros      1        null  null
  dis       2         A    dis
  dis       2         B    dis
  qual      3        null  null
  val       4        null  null
  prop      5        null  null
  neg       6        B     neg
  stal      7        null  null
  won       8         A    won
```

What I want to have happen is

```
PStage  StageOrder  ID    stage
  pros      1        null  null
  dis       2         A    dis
  qual      3        null  null
  val       4        null  null
  prop      5        null  null
  neg       6        null  null
  stal      7        null  null
  won       8         A    won
  pros      1        null  null
  dis       2         B    dis
  qual      3        null  null
  val       4        null  null
  prop      5        null  null
  neg       6        B     neg
  stal      7        null  null
  won       8        null  null
```

I am fine with ID repeating in all null spaces if that makes it work as well

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select a.*, c.*
from tableA a, (select distinct id from tableB) b
left join tableB c 
on b.id = c.id 
and PStage = stage
order by b.id, StageOrder
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]